# How to unmount USB mac disk with MacDrive

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, mount

If you have a USB external drive in Windows, you can right-click it and unmount it before unplugging. But if this USB drive is Mac formatted and mounted with the helper app MacDrive, the "Unmount" option is gone from the contextual menu. How can I safely remove a Mac formatted volume under Windows?

Answer (score 1):

This is according to Mediafour (makers of MacDrive): [How To...Safely remove drives from the computer](http://support.mediafour.com/entries/170458-macdrive-how-to-safely-remove-drives-from-the-computer)

> Even though FireWire and USB devices
>   are Plug & Play (i.e. they are ready
>   to use upon being plugged-in), you
>   should not just unplug them. By
>   unplugging a drive with a "hot"
>   connection, you can corrupt data on
>   your hard disk or other storage
>   device. It is important to note that
>   even disconnecting a device improperly
>   one time can cause file system
>   corruption.
>
> You can prevent such problems by
>   clicking the "Unplug/Eject" or "Safely
>   Remove Hardware" icon in the system
>   tray (down by the clock). The icon
>   looks like a gray box with with a
>   green arrow on top.
>
> You'll then be given a list of
>   removable devices that are currently
>   connected to your computer. Highlight
>   the device you would like to remove
>   and click "Stop".
>
> Windows should then prompt you that it
>   is safe to disconnect the device. If
>   not, this is an indication that some
>   part of Windows is using resources on
>   the disk. To clear this, reboot your
>   computer and before doing anything
>   else, try the above instructions
>   again.

Comment: The problem is, this icon is not visible for MacDrive volumes. Only for FAT/NTFS disks.

Comment: Maybe the MacDrive driver installed incorrectly. I doubt they would say to use the Safely Remove Hardware feature if MacDrive didn't support it. Try reinstalling it.